# Setting Linux environment variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am running Red Hat Linux Enterprise 5; I am always using the export command to set environment variables.

Are there any other ways to set environment variables and what are the advantages/disadvantages of them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is an excerpt from the Bash man page:

> export [-fn] [name[=word]] ...
>   export -p
>                 The  supplied names are marked for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands.  If the -f option  is
>                 given,  the names refer to functions...

If you only need the variable in the current environment, it's not necessary to use export.

```
var=value
```

**Edit:**

Without export: current environment only. With export: current environment and child environments.

Here's a demonstration of the affect of export on availability of a variable in a child environment and that changes in the child environment don't affect the parent:

```
$ var1=123
$ export var2=456
$ echo "parent [$var1] [$var2] [$var3]"
parent [123] [456] []
$ var3=789 bash -c 'echo "child [$var1] [$var2] [$var3]"; var1=111; var2=222; var3=333; echo "child [$var1] [$var2] [$var3]"'
child [] [456] [789]
child [111] [222] [333]
$ echo "parent [$var1] [$var2] [$var3]"
parent [123] [456] []
```

After the first echo (`echo "parent..."`) you see "123" and "456" because both `var1` and `var2` are active in the current environment. You don't see a value for `var3` because it's not set yet.

After the line that starts "`var3=...`" you don't see a value for `var1` because it wasn't exported. You *do* see a value for `var2` because it *was* exported. You see a value for `var3` because it was set for the child environment *only*.

(`bash -c` is equivalent to running a script with the contents of the argument to the `-c` option. A script or other executable or, in this case, the argument to `bash -c` becomes a child of the current environment which, as a result is, of course, the child's parent.)

In the "script" the values of the variable are changed. It now outputs those new values.

Once the "script" is finished, execution returns to the parent environment (the command line in this case). After the last echo, you see the original values because the changes made in the child environment do not affect the parent.

Comment: What means "in the current environment"? Current bash script or?

Comment: Yes, it means "in the current script" or "in the current interactive session". So that excludes executables or scripts that are run from within the current script or interactive session. That's the purpose of `export` - to make variables available to these child environments.

Comment: I find some conflicts from what you said. :-)

You said "So that excludes executables or scripts", pay attention to "exclude", but in what you quoted, you mentioned "The supplied names are marked for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands." -- it to be "include" (automatic exported to, or impact), and not "exclude". I am confused, could you clarify please?

Comment: @George2: See my edited answer for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You say that

> I am always using export command to set environment variable

By the way you worded that, it sounds like you are really trying to ask how do you make an environmental variable persists.  To do that would require you to place your `export VAR="foo"` statement in your $HOME/.bash_profile file (if you are using bash).  If you want that environmental variable to persist for all users but root, then add it to /etc/profile.  If you want it added for the root user too, then set it in /root/.bash_profile .

This will work for all login shells where bash is the shell of choice.  For non login shells, you need to use .bashrc.  I have no insights to offer for other shells :D

Comment: You might want to reread the section of the Bash man page regarding when those files are sourced.

Comment: Yup... I got login and interactive confused.  Editing my answer to reflect.  Thanks for the correction!

Comment: "make an environmental variable persists" -- what means persists?

Comment: "Persist" means that you want this variable to have this value each time a shell is started. It may or may not be necessary to export the variable depending on what its purpose is.

Comment: I have tried that if I open one terminal window and export a variable, then open another terminal window, the variable is not set. I think it is not persistent, any comments?

Comment: That means that you have not made it persistent. Try doing what **whaley** described.

Answer (score 1):

export is the most straightforward way to do it, so why not leave it at that?

```
export VARIABLE=value    # for Bourne, bash, and similar shells
setenv VARIABLE value    # for csh and similar shells
```

Comment: Bourne shell requires VARIABLE=value; export VARIABLE

Comment: This should work too...

Comment: @BloodPhilia, for bash, only one way to set environment variable?

Comment: @mpez0, what are the differences between using export and using =?

Comment: @George2 - When using VARIABLE=value, you're creating a local variable which is gone after current script execution. When using export, children processes inherit the variable values from their parent process.
For example:
`FOO=BAR; executethisprogram`

The program `executethisprogram` WILL NOT know the value of variable `FOO`. On the other hand, when using:
`FOO=BAR; export FOO; executethisprogram` 

The program `executethisprogram` WILL know the value of variable `FOO`.

Comment: in your sample "FOO=BAR; export FOO; executethisprogram", why executethisprogram is a subprocess of "export FOO" (please let me know if I am wrongly understand your points)? I think executethisprogram and "export FOO" should be two sequentially executed program and parallel relationship, why it is parent-child relationship?

Comment: executethisprogram is *not* a subprocess of "export FOO". It's a subprocess (child) of the script that calls it or the interactive (command-line) shell. `export FOO` is a command that marks the variable `FOO` so that it can be accessed by child processes of the envrionment in which the command was issued. That parent may be a script or an interactive shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

```
VAR=val application
```

For example:

```
LANG=C ls --help
```

output in English.

```
LANG=pl_PL ls --help
```

output in Polish (if avaliable).

In the past in sh you couldn't do export VAL=val.
You had to

```
VAL=val; export VAL
```

Comment: I am confused about "VAR=val application", what means val and what means application?

Comment: These examples set the value of the variable for the child environment (`ls`, for example) without affecting the value of that variable in the current (parent) environment.

Comment: ls is child environment of what? I am confused.

Comment: `ls` is a child of the process from which it was run. If I type `ls` at a command prompt, the interactive shell is the parent and `ls` is the child. If I have a script that uses `ls` then the script is the parent and `ls` is the child.