# environment variable issue in shell

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I am using Red Hat Linux Enterprise 5. I know the theory that -- using export to set environment variable, the environment variable will apply to current and child environment, but without using export to set environment variable, the environment variable will only apply to the current environment.

My confusion is, what is the exact definition of "child environment" and "current environment"? For example,

```
$ var1=123
$ echo "Hello [$var1]"
```

the value of var1 (which is 123) is printed in shell, but I think echo is a command invoked by current shell, and it (the echo command) should be a child environment of current shell and the value of var1 should not (because not using export var1=123) impact echo. Any comments?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable is expanded in the current environment.

```
$ set -x    # turn on tracing
$ var1=123
+ var1=123
$ echo "Hello [$var1]"
+ echo 'Hello [123]'
Hello [123]
$ set +x
```

As you can see from the trace (the lines beginning with "+"), `echo` sees "Hello [123]". It never gets the variable.

As you saw from [**gogiel's** answer](https://superuser.com/questions/143413/linux-environment-variables/143422#143422) to your other question, exported environment variables do affect the environment of the child:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
$ declare -p LANG   # the response includes "-x" which shows the variable is already marked for export
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
$ ls --help | head -n 4
Usage: ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).
Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort.
$ LANG=es_MX.utf8 ls --help | head -n 4
Uso: ls [OPCIÓN]... [FICHERO]...
Muestra información acerca de los ARCHIVOS (del directorio actual por defecto).
Ordena las entradas alfabéticamente si no se especifica ninguna de las opciones -cftuSUX ni --sort.
```

Or I could have set the value of `LANG` in the current environment and since it's exported it would be inherited by the child environment:

```
$ LANG=es_MX.utf8
$ grep --help | head -n 4
Modo de empleo: grep [OPCIÓN]... PATRÓN [FICHERO]...
Busca un PATRÓN en algún ARCHIVO o entrada estándar.
PATTERN es, por omisión, una expresión regular básica (BRE).
Ejemplo: grep -i '¡Hola, mundo!' menu.h main.c
$ sed --help | head -n 4
Uso: sed [OPCIÓN]... {guión-sólo-si-no-hay-otro-guión} [fichero-entrada]...

  -n, --quiet, --silent
                 suprime la muestra automática del espacio de patrones
$ while [[ = 4 ]]    # create an error on purpose to show Spanish error message
bash: se esperaba un operador binario condicional
bash: error sintáctico cerca de `4'
```

**Edit:**

Here is a simple script (let's call it `showvars`) so you can see what's going on both inside and outside.

```
#!/bin/bash
arguments="$@"
printf "The script has started.\n"
printf "These are the parameters passed to the script: [$arguments]\n"
scriptvar=100
printf "This is the value of scriptvar: [$scriptvar]\n"
printf "This is the value of exportvar: [$exportvar]\n"
printf "This is the value of shellvar: [$shellvar]\n"
printf "This is the value of commandvar: [$commandvar]\n"
printf "The script has ended.\n"
```

Now we do these steps at a shell prompt:

```
$ shellvar=200
$ export exportvar=300
$ ./showvars 400 $shellvar 500
The script has started.
These are the parameters passed to the script: [400 200 500]
This is the value of scriptvar: [100]
This is the value of exportvar: [300]
This is the value of shellvar: []
This is the value of commandvar: []
The script has ended.
$ commandvar=600 ./showvars 400 $shellvar 500
The script has started.
These are the parameters passed to the script: [400 200 500]
This is the value of scriptvar: [100]
This is the value of exportvar: [300]
This is the value of shellvar: []
This is the value of commandvar: [600]
The script has ended.
$ printf "This is the value of commandvar: [$commandvar]\n"
This is the value of commandvar: []
$ commandvar=600
$ ./showvars 400 $shellvar 500
The script has started.
These are the parameters passed to the script: [400 200 500]
This is the value of scriptvar: [100]
This is the value of exportvar: [300]
This is the value of shellvar: []
This is the value of commandvar: []
The script has ended.
$ printf "This is the value of scriptvar: [$scriptvar]\n"
This is the value of scriptvar: []
$ printf "This is the value of exportvar: [$exportvar]\n"
This is the value of exportvar: [300]
$ printf "This is the value of shellvar: [$shellvar]\n"
This is the value of shellvar: [200]
$ printf "This is the value of commandvar: [$commandvar]\n"
This is the value of commandvar: [600]
```

As you can see `shellvar` is not available inside the script and `scriptvar` is not available outside it. Since `exportvar` is exported, it's available both inside and outside the script. And `commandvar` is only available inside the script when it's passed on the command line when calling the script. If it's set in the interactive environment and then the script is called, it's available only in the interactive environment.

Comment: Why you say "sees "Hello [123]". It never gets the variable"? It is obvious that variable value 123 is taken by this statement and Hello [123] is printed, other than Hello[]? Any comments?

Comment: Yes, the variable is expanded by the shell (it replaces the variable with its value) and the value is passed to `echo`. So `echo` never sees the variable, just its value.

Comment: Hi Dennis, sorry for my confusion again. I think if we do not use export, then the variable value can not be seen from child environment, correct? I think command like ls and echo are child environment (which is command executed/invoked by current shell), so in your sample you set var1 without export, command like echo or ls should not know its value (which is 123), why in your sample, echo (as a child environment of current shell) knows the value 123? Please correct me for anything wrong. Have a nice weekend!

Comment: @George2: Look at the trace at the top of my answer. The "$" is the shell prompt. I type `echo "Hello [$var1]"` and the next line (that starts with "+") shows what actually happens. The shell (Bash) tells `echo` to output "123". The shell replaces the name of the variable with its value *before* it gives it to `echo` so `echo` never sees the variable it only sees the *value* passed as a parameter. I'm going to add a small script to my answer that will show what's going on by letting you see inside the process. It will take me a few minutes, so check back if it's not there yet.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, your reply is so informative! Almost all of my confusions are resolved. The last question, about variable which is using export to set. Normally it will impact not only current shell, but also sub-environment like script/executable invoked by current shell. Besides script/executable, any other entities which will be impacted the same way as script/executable? I am also not sure whether shell command like "mkdir" will be treated as sub-environments as well?

Comment: @George2: What kind of other entities? `mkdir` is a child of whatever environment it's invoked from - the interactive shell or a script, for example. Usually such executables are only affected by exported environment variables that are documented in their `man` pages. The one type of environment variable that is often effective even though it's not documented in individual `man` pages is the set of locale related variables such as `LANG` demonstrated in some of the examples above.

Comment: "mkdir is a child of whatever environment it's invoked from" -- my confusion is what kinds of things on Linux are child, I know executables, scripts are child. But I am not sure whether command like mkdir is a child of current environment or not? Is command like echo also child of current environment?

Comment: executables, scripts, commands, yes.

Comment: but echo is an exception? It is a command but can receive variable value from parent shell?

Comment: No, not an exception. Look at `file="/etc/passwd"; ls -l "$file"` Here `ls` is receiving a variable's value from the parent shell. The *value* **not** *the variable itself*.